# How to choose HTTP status code for unavailable event

Tags: node.js, rest, http-status-codes, http-status

**Description:**

The user inquires about the availability of the event on a given day.

**Question:** 
Which response code should I send back if new event can not be created on this day? 404? 400? 422?

**My choice:**
I chose the "404 Not Found" status code:

```
{
  "statusCode": 404,
  "error": "Not Found",
  "message": "The event can not be created on the selected date."
}
```

Comment: You say "inquire" and then your message says "create". Which is it?

Comment: I just want to check if the event is available on a given day or is not available. If it is not available, I want to send back the error. However, I do not know what the status code should I use.

Answer (score 0):

As a response to a POST request I would use the 422 Unprocessable Entity status code along with a description of why the request could not be processed.

If you only want to test if there is already an event at this day, perform a GET request (for example: /event/2019-06-01) to check if it exists.
If it does not exist yet, respond with a 404 not found.

Answer (score -1):

Your question is entirely opinion based. You should try learning about various [status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) and their reasons. In your case, you may find status code [410](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#410) useful, but again, this is entirely opinion based.